# Are these termites

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Found a large number of these trapped between my window and the window frame. Are they termites?

Location: Eastern Massachusetts, USA[image]

Comment: What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ant in the genus *Camponotus*. It can only be identified from the habitus on your picture, but clues are that there is only one element between the thorax and the gaster (Formicinae) and the head is large, this with the color and texture pattern leads to *Camponotus sp*.

Refer to

> Bolton, B., Alpert, G., Ward, P. S., & Naskrecki, P. (2006). Bolton’s
>   Catalogue of Ants of the World. Cambridge: Harvard.

for more detail on the identification.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Based on the morphology of the abdomen and antennae as well as the darker coloration, I'm going to say they are not. Looks a bit more ant-like (see picture).

Comment: Thank you, jmc1094. Mine do not have wings. Is it a seasonal thing?

Comment: Not necessarily, I just chose that figure as it illustrates differences in the body types pretty clearly.

Comment: Definitely an ant. Ants have elbowed antennae.

Comment: Termites are often nearly white and look as if the have 2 body sections instead of 3 as a typical insect.